# How to fetch data from database on scroll?

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I am using CachedRowSet in the java application to pull data from database. Suppose, if a query return 10,000 rows, my app will hang till i got all the rows.

Instead of that, i need to show the complete result only on scrolling. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: In this case, You have to use XSL to display. What is the front end you are displaying?

Comment: I believe this would depend on your UI. Are you using a web-based UI, Swing, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You may choose to implement your own lazy loading List which will load values page by page as accessed. There are many tutorials on this on internet check this one : http://blog.projectnibble.org/2009/07/22/java-generic-paged-lazy-list-with-jsfjpa-example-implementation/